# Does SAP Hybris uses Resful services or it can be use using SOAP too? Can we use AngularJS at UI?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on `SAP Hybris` and newbie in that. If we talk about standard `SOA` architecture or `Web based` application, now a days applications are developed using `AngularJS` at UI and `Spring MVC + Spring RestFul` services at the backend.

We are looking to developed the end to end development for our `eCommerce` site using `SAP Hybris`. We're looking to keep the architecture like AngularJS at UI and **Spring MVC + Spring RESTFul** services at the `backend` and also **Apache Solr** for `index based searching`. Will this approach be work?

Or SAP Hybris is proritary tool and we can do any customizations. Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem using Angular as frontend. Hybris provides a good out of the box Web Services REST API and if you don't like it, you can extend it however you need. If you need a SOAP service to connect to Hybris backend, you have to create one yourself.

In general Hybris is quite customizable so it can cover your needs. Here are some reference links:

[Hybris Platform Web Services](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8bea21ae86691014ba63caf92420bcf6.html)
[Some docs](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/api/cis2/rest-api-docs/index.html)

[Angular widget docs](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/91cbb87ea5164d13a42aa270e8b0513f.html)

Answer (score 0):

SAP hybris is a proprietary solution which is highly customizable. I mean you can do whatever you want if you're willing to do some customization.

Out of the box hybris expose some REST WS. You can also use SOAP if you need, you just have to develop it.

FYI, Spring is already integrated in hybris and it's one of the main framework used by hybris. Solr is also already integrated for indexing. Finally you just have to develop your front layer with Angular if you want.